# Coq - How to show that the first argument of a function is decreasing?

Tags: coq

I'm working through [this](http://www.cis.upenn.edu/~bcpierce/sf/Basics.html#lab39) Coq tutorial and I'm stuck with the one of the last exercises.
I defined a datatype for the binary representation of natural numbers and now I want to convert natural numbers to this representation:

```
Inductive bin : Type :=
  | BO : bin
  | TO : bin -> bin
  | T1 : bin -> bin.
```

My first naive approach was this:

```
Fixpoint divmod_2 (n : nat) :=
  match n with
  | O => (O, 0)
  | S O => (O, 1)
  | S (S n') => match (divmod_2 n') with
                | (q, u') => ((S q), u')
                end
  end.

Fixpoint to_bin (n : nat) : bin :=
  match n with
  | O => BO
  | S n' => match divmod_2 n' with
            | (q, 0) => TO (to_bin q)
            | (q, 1) => T1 (to_bin q)
            | (_, _) => BO
            end
  end.
```

Coq stops at the definition of `to_bin` saying:

```
Error:
Recursive definition of to_bin is ill-formed.
In environment
to_bin : nat -> bin
n : nat
n' : nat
q : nat
n0 : nat
Recursive call to to_bin has principal argument equal to "q" instead of
"n'".
```

**So here's the question: How do I fix this `to_bin` function ?

Do I have to provide a proof for well founded recursion as described [here](http://adam.chlipala.net/cpdt/html/GeneralRec.html) ?

I assume that there is a simpler solution since it's a newbie tutorial ?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the easiest solution would be to define a successor function for binary naturals first, and then to use it to convert the successor of unary naturals.

Comment: That is the proper way to do it. Just recur normally to compute `to_bin n'`, and now you just need to add one to that `bin` number, which you can do easily by writing a `succ : bin -> bin` and simple pattern-matching. As Exercise 5 points out, the other modes of recursion are for later in the book.

Comment: I concur, you write to write a function nat -> bin so your "thinking" should consider the two questions 1/ what is the value of my function on 0; 2/ if I already know the value on p, what will be the value on (S p).  So, you follow the structure of the input.  Your thinking follows the structure of the output, which why you get stuck.